# Microsoft Excel if value of B1 >100 display A1 (on another sheet)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Been trying to figure out if it is possible to make a statement where I have a table and another sheet where I want to display the top 5 greatest values that are over 100

- Column A has the name and column B has the value
- Sheet 1 I want to display IF column B is greater than 100 display both the name and the value on sheet 1

But I am hitting a brick wall with If and Index statements :(

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to "display the top 5 " OR "display IF column B is greater than 100"? However, for both issues pivot table seems to be a good solution.

Comment: I have tried =INDEX('sheet2'!F5:F85,">100")+IF('sheet2'!C5:C85,'sheet2'!F5:F85) and tried other variables but I think I might of been using the wrong ones :D will have a look at a pivot table,

But what I am trying to do is have a 2 column table that displays the name in col A and a value of col A in col B

Answer (score 1):

Based on Vasim's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel use

```
=VLOOKUP(LARGE(B1:B10,ROW()),A1:B10,2,0)
```

except add the sheet references to A1:A10 and A1:B10.

Once you have the top 5 values displaying on Sheet2 use a simple IF statement to only show them when their value is >100. Roughly...

```
=IF(LARGE('Sheet1'!A1:A10,ROW()) > 100, VLOOKUP(LARGE(B1:B10,ROW()),A1:B10,2,0), '')
```

It may require some column tweaks based on your data. As mentioned in Vasim's answer you will need to modify the value coming from ROW() if you don't have the list at the top of the sheet.